# How to create SVG shapes based on data?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have structure with data and shapes definition:

```
var data = [
  {
    "id": "first",
    "shapes": [
      {
        "shape": "polygon",
        "points": [["8","64"],["8","356"],["98","356"],["98","64"]]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "second",
    "shapes": [
      {
        "shape": "ellipse",
        "cx": "63", "cy": "306", "rx": "27","ry": "18"
      }, {
        "shape": "polygon",
        "points": [["174","262"],["171","252"],["167","262"]]
      }
    ]
  }   
];    // in the data may be stored any SVG shape
```

I would like to create SVG:

```
<svg width="218" height="400">
  <g transform="translate(0,400) scale(1,-1)">
    <g>
      <polygon points="8,64 8,356 98,356 98,64"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <ellipse cx="63" cy="306" rx="27" ry="18"/>
      <polygon points="174,262 171,252 167,262"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

For each `data` element I'm appending `<g>`:

```
var groups = svg.selectAll("g").data(data, function (d) {
  return d.id;
});
groups.enter().append("g");
```

Now I'm binding data for group shapes:

```
var shapes = groups.selectAll(".shape").data(function (d) {
  return d.shapes;
}, function(d,i){return [d.shape,i].join('-');});
```

So far it was as expected. Now I want to for each entering DOM node dispatch drawing function with proper shape but apparently `shapes.enter().each()` is not working in this context (not defined). I suppose it works rather on each DOM node than on each data to be bound. And this is working:

```
shapes.enter().append("g").each(function(draw, i) {
  var shape = draw.shape;
  d3.select(this).call(drawer[shape]);
});
```

But painful side-effect is that SVG has two levels of `<g>`:

```
<svg width="218" height="400">
  <g transform="translate(0,400) scale(1,-1)">
    <g>
      <g>
        <polygon points="8,64 8,356 98,356 98,64"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  ...
</svg>
```

How to get rid of that? How to build data based shapes correctly?

Comment: can you put this in a jsfiddle or jsbin. I think i would check on each function to see what output is being rendered and maybe get svg shape out as string and append it into innerHtml within each loop.

Comment: You could do something along those lines with a [superformula](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1021103) or with precomputed shapes like [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062383).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to add basic shapes based on data provided by AmeliaBR are ok but slightly outside d3.js API. After long consideration I've decided to add answer my own question.

Inspiration for searching other solution was comment of Lars Kotthoff under question suggesting using paths instead of primitive SVG shapes. In this approach instead of adding second level of `<g>` there should be added `<path>`:

```
shapes.enter().append("path").attr("d", function(d) {
  return drawer[d.shape](d);
});
```

Original `drawer` object generating basic shapes would return value for attribute `d` of `<path>`.

```
    var drawer = {
        polygon: function (d) {
            return [
                "M", d.points[0].join(','),
                "L", d.points
                  .slice(1, d.points.length)
                  .map(function (e) {
                    return e.join(",")
                }), "Z"].join(" ");
        },
        ellipse: function (d) {
            return [
                'M', [d.cx, d.cy].join(','),
                'm', [-d.rx, 0].join(','),
                'a', [d.rx, d.ry].join(','),
                0, "1,0", [2 * d.rx, 0].join(','),
                'a', [d.rx, d.ry].join(','),
                0, "1,0", [-2 * d.rx, 0].join(',')].join(' ');
        },
        circle: function (d) {
            return this.ellipse({
                cx: d.cx,
                cy: d.cy,
                rx: d.r,
                ry: d.r
            });
        },
        rect: function (d) {
            return this.polygon({
                points: [
                    [d.x, d.y],
                    [d.x + d.width, d.y],
                    [d.x + d.width, d.y + d.height],
                    [d.x, d.y + d.height]
                ]
            });
        },
        path: function (d) {
            return d.d;
        }
};
```

Working example you can check at http://fiddle.jshell.net/daKkJ/4/

Comment: Nice conversion function.  So long as there was no logical reason for maintaining the separate element types this is probably the optimal solution since now all your elements are a uniform set of "path" elements which accept the same attributes (e.g., x and y for top left corner).

Answer (score 3):

Tricky question.  Shame that you can't call each on an enter() selection.  <del>Neither can you use a `function(d){}` in an append statement.</del>(See comments)

But I got it working, using a Javascript [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) call on the data array itself.  It calls your function with the array entry, index, and array itself as parameters, and you can specify a `this` context -- I just passed in the desired parent element as a selection.

The fabulous fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/994XM/1/
(simpler than your case, but should be able to adapt easily)

It's a bit confusing since the D3 code inside the `forEach` is all *per element*, with the `d` and `i` values already available for you, so you don't need any internal functions in your D3 method calls.  But once you figure that out, it all works.

Comment: You can actually use a function that returns the DOM element to be appended in `.append()`.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff: that's what it says in the spec, but it throws a `NotFoundError` when run.  The first call to the anonymous function inside `append()` gets passed data correctly but it errors out on return -- even if I just return a static string.  I assume the problem is the reference to `this` isn't properly set in the actual append function call.  Here's [the example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/994XM/6/) I tried, any suggestions welcome.  If you agree that it *should* work, it might be worth bringing it up as an issue on gitHub.

Comment: You need to create and return the actual DOM element -- http://fiddle.jshell.net/994XM/7/

Comment: Ah, thanks @Lars, hadn't read the API carefully enough.  So, for @Marcin, I think this is the "proper" way to do it.  I've tidied up the fiddle so the rest of the attributes of the shapes are set nicely here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/994XM/9/  But the important line that Lars added is `shapes.enter().append(function(d,i) {
        return document.createElement(d.type); 
        })`: 
The function call creates the element using plain old Javascript and returns it to the D3 append method.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Thank you for answers. I'm considering iterating `forEach()` through entering data nodes and creating DOM nodes via `document` API as little bit outside d3.js API. I would prefer modifying sets and creating nodes using directly D3.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question through Google, and the jsfiddles linked to above have ceased to work. You now have to call document.createElementNS, giving it the SVG namespace, otherwise the shapes don't show up.

I created an updated [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/klortho/994XM/13/). I also cleaned out a lot of the unnecessary bits, so it should be easier to see what's going on.

Comment: I would stick with path based shapes because it gives possibility to make a smooth tween between them.

Comment: Sure, that's fine for you, but in my case, I wanted to have rectangles or circles, depending on the "node type". A given node never changes type, so there's no need to tween.
Also, I wanted to let others know that I fixed the fiddle -- the ones linked to above are broken.