# Append datum-specific element on enter selection

Tags: d3.js

I want to append "icons" (path, rect or circle-elements) to my enter-selection based on the type supplied in the data. Has anybody any idea?

```
var data = [ 
    {
        type: "apple" // -> Icon should be a rect
        text: "Demo"
    },
    {
        type: "banana" // -> Icon should be a circle
        text: "Demo"
    },
    {
        type: "peach" // -> Icon should be a path
        text: "Demo"
    },
    {
        type: "pear" // -> Icon should be a rect
        text: "Demo"
    },
];

d3.selectAll(".fruit")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .each(function(d, i) { // <- Each is not a function of enter selection
    switch(d.type) {
        case "apple":
            var type = "rect";
            break;
        case "banana":
            var type = "circle";
            break;
        case "peach":
            var type = "path";
            break;
        case "pear":
            var type = "rect";
            break;
        default:
            var type = "rect";
            break;
    }
    this.append(type);
  });
```

My example doesn't work because .each() is no function of the enter selection. Has anybody an idea?

thx

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753636/how-to-create-svg-shapes-based-on-data

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to accomplish this task using `.each`. You can process the data before binding to dom elements using pure javascript.

```
var data = [{
    type: "apple",
    text: "Demo"
}, {
    type: "banana",
    text: "Demo"
}, {
    type: "peach",
    text: "Demo"
}, {
    type: "pear",
    text: "Demo"
}, ];

data.forEach(function(d) {
    switch (d.type) {
        case "apple":
            var type = "rect";
            break;
        case "banana":
            var type = "circle";
            break;
        case "peach":
            var type = "path";
            break;
        case "pear":
            var type = "rect";
            break;
        default:
            var type = "rect";
            break;
    }
    d.icon = type;
});
console.log(data); //Now, each object will contain icon property according to it's type

var selection = d3.selectAll(".fruit")
    .data(data)
    .enter();
```